# "Open In Git Shell" command

Tags: github, github-for-windows

On Github for Windows I can right click on a project, select "Open In Git Shell" and I can execute git commands against that project.

What will be the direct command line command for opening git console for my project (without opening Github for Windows)? It must be something easy, but I am lost in Google and SO search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, this command opens up a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) session instead of a standard Windows `cmd.exe` session. So first you should run "Git Shell" from the start menu (Git Shell will invoke a Bash session for you). Then simply `cd` to the root directory of your repository.

Note that Bash uses Unix syntax for paths, unlike from `cmd.exe` and other Windows software. It uses forward slashes instead of backslashes, and "dives" are rooted at `/`. So, for example, to work on a repository located at `C:\Users\SM79\Desktop\My Project\` you would run something like `cd /c/Users/SM79/Desktop/My\ Project/`.

Tab completion can be very helpful, especially when working with directories like `My Project` that contain spaces. (Typing the `My` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> should complete the directory, including escapes for spaces or other reserved characters, as far as possible without ambiguity.)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, on my system it is called Git Shell, not Git Bash.

Comment: @SM79 My mistake, I was answering from memory. I've updated my answer.